# Comparing two lists for same value

Tags: python, list, binary

Let's say I have 3 lists:

```
a = [0,0,0,1,1]
b = [1,0,0,0,0]
c = [1,1,1,0,0]
```

I want to return False whenever there are 1's at the same position, so for 'b & c' it would return False, because they both have a one at index 0, 'a & b' and 'a & c' should return True in this case.

The way I would do it is:

```
for i in range(0, len(a)):
   if a[i] == 1 and b[i] == 1:
      return False
return True
```

Though I feel this is very inefficient. Is there an easier and more efficient way to do this? I was thinking of using binary AND, but not sure how to implement that.

Comment: For vanilla Python, no. You may want to take a look at numpy or numba for faster implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for one liner. Here it is:

`any([False if a[i] == 1 and b[i] == 1 else True for i in range(0, len(a))])`

Sorry did not test it. Here is modified version with test:

```
>>> a = [0,0,0,1,1]
>>> b = [1,0,0,0,0]
>>> c = [1,1,1,0,0]
>>> def f(a,b):
...   return all([False if a[i] == 1 and b[i] == 1 else True for i in range(0, len(a))])
...
>>> print(f(a,b), f(b,c), f(a,c))
True False True
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, since `any` returns once a `True` is found, but you're returning `False` for the interesting case. What would work is `not any([a[i] == 1 and c[i] == 1 for i in range(len(a))])`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` makes it a bit more robust, as you don't need to worry about IndexErrors:

```py
for elem_a, elem_b in zip(a, b):
    if elem_a and elem_b:
        return False
return True
```

You don't need binary and if you know the lists contain either 0s or 1s. Python interprets 0 as `False` in this case.